# What are the advantages and disadvantages of dropping iOS 7 support?

Tags: ios

What are the advantages and disadvantages for dropping support for iOS 7? I am thinking about dropping it but just want to make sure I will not be making a grievous mistake.

Comment: you can take decision according to your targeted users and also targeted country,if you are targeting INDIA,CHINA,etc than you can't underestimate iPhone 4.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping iOS 7 means that you can go directly to iOS 9 because all iOS 8 devices are supported by iOS 9.

Disadvantages:

- You drop support for iPhone 4
- ... that's pretty much it.

Advantages

- Access to newer APIs. Too many to list down here.
- Much better right-to-left support (very important if you have many customers in the middle east)
- App thinning – allows faster download, primarily for purchases over cellular.
- Watch connectivity framework.

All in all this is really a business decision and you should look at your analytics to decide. The decisive factors is primarily how many *active* iPhone 4 users that you have and whether it is still worth your time to cater them.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to consider is that iPhone 4 can't be upgraded to iOS 8, and that depending on unofficial stats, iOS 7 represents more than 10% of the iPhones. For example : https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/